# Ansible connectivity from Control Host to Remote Host : Alternate to Passwordless SSH

Tags: ansible

We are in the midway of implementing Ansible CI for app deployment. For connecting the Remote host from Control Host , we used passwordless SSH authentication (by adding SSH key to authorized_keys).

But with recent changes, Unix team not allowing this any more on higher env as corporate unix policy. So have to use the password way.

The user with which Ansible running & connecting to Remote machine is a sudo user & does not have a password for itself.

So in this case, how do we connect from Control Host to Remote host, without the SSH key?

Comment: Do you have access to a user that has a password and can connect to the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, I do.. That would be my unix login user.. Then I sudo to power user.

Answer (score -1):

while running the ansible playbook we get an option to provide the user using which we can do ssh --user . Also the same configuration can be achieved by providing the configuration in the inventory file.

`ansible_user=<user_name>`

For password you can use vault

I am editing the answer to provide info that we can use other user than the one with which ansible is installed. You can create a new user which has password or passwordless authentication setup.

Hope so this helps.

Cheers,
Yash